# how to check if the Expect->spawn($command) is success?

Tags: perl, unix, exit, spawn, expect.pm

I am passing an scp command in `Expect->spawn($command)`, I am also passing the password or password + OTP based on a `$object->expect()`.
Could you let me know if there is a way to determine if the command has been run successfully ?

I'm trying `$object->after()` , but it's giving the password prompt which is the previous `$object->expect()`
also explored `$object->exitstatus()` , it'll be empty since the object is not exited.

```
my $expect_obj = new Expect;
 $expect_obj->log_stdout(0);
 my $spawn = $expect_obj->spawn(split/\s+/, "scp $src $dest");
 my $pos = $expect_obj->expect(60,
                           [qr/password.*: $/, sub {my $self = shift; $self->send("$pass\n")}],
                        );
```

How do I determine if the command is successful ?

Comment: See also [Net::SSH2::Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Expect) and [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Expect is giving a choice to match the prompt and send the input based on the match.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I determine if the command is successful ?

You can use [waitpid](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid) as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632210/2173773) answer. It will assign the exit code of the child to `$?` (`$CHILD_ERROR`), see more information in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar). Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Expect;

my $pass = 'my_password';
my $src = 'a_file.txt';
my $dest = 'user@172.17.0.2:';
my $port = 2222;
my @params = ('-P', $port, $src, $dest);
my $expect = Expect->new();
$expect->log_stdout(0);
my $spawn = $expect->spawn("scp", @params) or die "Cannot spawn scp: $!\n";
my $child_pid = $expect->pid();
my ($pos, $error, $match, $before, $after) = $expect->expect(
    60,
    [qr/password.*: $/, sub {my $self = shift; $self->send("$pass\n")}],
);
my $res = waitpid $child_pid, 0;
if ($res == $child_pid) {
    my $exit_code = $? >> 8;
    if ($exit_code == 0) {
        say "scp exited successfully";
    }
    else {
        say "scp failed with exit code $exit_code";
    }
}
elsif ($res == -1) {
    say "Child process $child_pid does not exist";
}
else {
    say "Unexpected: waitpid() return unknown child pid: $res";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland , I will try this approach and see if it works.

Comment: $expect->pid() / $child_pid is becoming blank since the process completes, so, $res is always -1.